# Binary to decimal and decimal to binary converters

Tags: python

Can someone please explain these lines of Python program for me:

```
b =input("What number would you like to convert into Binary? ")
convert = lambda d: bin(int(d)) [2:]
print(b + " is " + convert(b) + " in Binary")
```

And also these lines of code:

```
b = input("What Binary number would you like to convert into Decimal? ")
convert= lambda b: str(int(b, 2))
print(b + " is " + convert(b) + " in Decimal")
```

Comment: Which part don't you understand? The `lambda` expression?

Comment: For those who (like me) wonder what on earth denary means: most people call that number system decimal (ie, base 10) :)

Comment: FWIW, I edited the title and changed denary/dinery to decimal.

Answer (score 3):

The `lambda` expression is a way of defining a short function, e.g.

```
f = lambda x: x**2 # e.g. f(2) == 4
```

is equivalent to

```
def f(x):
    return x**2
```

`int(d)` converts `d` into an integer. `bin(...)` takes that integer and converts it into a binary string, which looks like:

```
bin(int(3)) == '0b11'
```

Note that the first two characters, `0b`, are not really part of the number, so we use slice notation `[2:]` to return everything from index `2` onwards:

```
'0b11'[2:] == '11'
```

Finally, the optional second argument to `int` sets the base that should be used for converting the argument; in this case, base `2` (binary):

```
int('11', 2) == 3
```

You can use this for other bases, too, e.g. `16` (hexadecimal):

```
int('11', 16) == 17
```

Answer (score 0):

Decimal to binary:

```
bin(124)
```

This will give the value `'0b1111100'`
Binary to decimal:

```
int('0b1111100', 2)
```

This will give the value `124`

Answer (score 0):

decimal to binary conversion 
if n=5

```
bin=lambda x : format(x,'b')
print(bin(n))
```

First statement will make bin a function which will take a argument and convert it into binary, format is used to convert int to binary and lambda to fetch the binary digits.

This will help you to print binary number